# how can solve form is null in react-hook-form form controller?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Error: Uncaught TypeError: methods is nul

I used react hook form in my project like following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useController, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

interface formTypes {
    fullname: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    confirmPassword: string,
    phone: string,
    gender: string,
    countries: string
}


const NewForm = () => {
    const { field } = useController({
        name: 'fullname', rules: {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i
        }
    })

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data: formTypes) => console.log(data);
    console.log(errors);


    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                {/* <input type="text" placeholder="username" {...register("username", {
                    required: true, maxLength: 15, pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i
                })} /> */}
                <input {...field} />
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" {...register("password", { required: true, min: 4 })} />
                <input type="password" placeholder="confirmPassword" {...register("confirmPassword", { maxLength: 5 })} />

                <input {...register("gender", { required: true })} type="radio" value="male" />
                <input {...register("gender", { required: true })} type="radio" value="female" />
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" {...register("email", { pattern: /(^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1, 3}\.[0-9]{1, 3}\.[0-9]{1, 3}\.[0-9]{1, 3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$)/i })} />
                <input type="tel" placeholder="phone" {...register("phone", { pattern: /(^(\+98|0)?\d{10}$)/i })} />
                <select {...register("city")}>
                    <option value="tehran">tehran</option>
                    <option value="shiraz">shiraz</option>
                    <option value="tabriz">tabriz</option>
                </select>

                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </>
    );


}
export default NewForm
```

i don't know why i receive the following error because i hadn't insert any data to my form (actually the page crashed because existing error) and it gives me an error.
how can i solved it and how can use fom provider react-hook-form in my project?

```
Uncaught TypeError: methods is null
    useController useController.ts:32
    NewForm NewForm.tsx:17
    React 12
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24
```

NOTE: i write defaultValue but it still receive following error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve `control` from `useForm` hook and pass it to the `useController` hook as a prop like this:

```
const {
    control,
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
} = useForm();
const { field } = useController({
    control: control,
    name: "fullname",
    rules: {
      required: true,
      pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i
    }
});
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-ikiz20?file=/src/NewForm.tsx) for a live working example of your form.